# Why do C# methods have 2 separate flags: HasThis and IsStatic

Tags: c#, methods, static-methods, cil, reflector

I have been playing with Reflector and Reflexil, but when I created a static method, it didn't work. On some ispection, I found that methods have 2 different parameters/flags: `IsStatic` and `HasThis`.

[image: 2 different flags: IsStatic and HasThis]

What is the diference? Or is there no difference and one of the flags is simply unused? I have looked at extension methods and constructors, however extension methods are marked as normal static methods, and constructors as normal member methods (in regard to these 2 flags).

Comment: `HasThis` passes `this` to the target method (cannot be used for static methods). `IsStatic` is a property indicating that the method is static.

Comment: I think this is the documentation for that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.callingconventions(v=vs.110).aspx  It's not related to extension methods.

Comment: It seems that `HasThis` is a member of the `CallingConventions` enum, used for interop, whereas `IsStatic` is a member of the `System.Reflection.MethodBase` class.

Comment: The tool crams two distinct metadata definitions together, MethodDef and MethodDefSig.  IsStatic comes from MethodDef, HasThis comes from MethodDefSig.  Ecma-335, section II chapter 22.26 demands that they correspond for a method, HasThis must always be the inverse of IsStatic.  So whatever the real problem might be, this isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflexil displays together two sets of flags - method atttributes from the method definition in case of *IsStatic*, and calling conventions from the method signature definition in case of *HasThis*.

Method attributes contain general information about a specific method, like its accessibility, abstract/virtual/sealed status etc. (e.g. `Static`), while the signature is what the method takes and returns and how, which can be separated into several calling conventions.

The managed calling conventions are `DEFAULT`, `VARARG`, `HASTHIS` and `EXPLICITTHIS`. `HASTHIS` (`instance` in CIL) simply means that the `this` instance is internally passed as the first argument to the method (referenced by `ldarg.0`).

`HASTHIS` is useful in places where you would only be able to use a method signature, like in function pointers or the `calli` instruction (both unavailable in C#, though not in C++/CLI). However, `EXPLICITTHIS` would be more appropriate on these occasions.

The `Static` flag may not be needed for methods, but is certainly required for fields, as they have no calling convention, so probably consistency is the reason.

So, conceptually they are a bit different, but technically mean the same thing.

While in theory a non-static method may not need a `this` reference, setting both flags at the same time is prohibited, and *ilasm* doesn't allow me to construct a method with both flags on or off, setting them both based only on the presence of the `static` keyword.

---

Extension methods are only a C# thing, the "this" reference is the actual first parameter of the method and the rest is syntactic sugar.

Comment: C#, and this is important difference to java, has "static extensions", other way to realize "method" with "this" pointer. Maybe this is background to wider set of properties???

Comment: @JacekCz Sorry, what is the question?